# How to move all files from NSDocumentDirectory to NSCachesDirectory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to move all of the documents that reside in the NSDocumentDirectory to the NSCachesDirectory, and then delete all of those NSDocument files upon the first app launch of my next version update to my app. The only reason I'm doing this is to abide by Apple's iOS data storage guidelines, as my app update was rejected for saving .PDF files to the NSDocumentsDirectory (I have no clue why, because the app has never been rejected for this until this update (app is almost 2 years old, and I have been saving .PDFs this way since day 1), maybe I got a strict reviewer?)

I need to move all of the user's already downloaded .PDF files to the NSCachesDirectory and then delete them from the NSDocumentDirectory.

Is there a simple way this can be accomplished?

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

I tried this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
NSUserDefaults      *Defaults;
 int                 launchCount;

 Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 launchCount = [Defaults integerForKey:@"launchCount" ] + 1;
 [Defaults setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];
 [Defaults synchronize];

if(launchCount == 1) {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *path2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *dest = [path2 objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *Contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];

    for(NSString *source in Contents)
    {
        if(![fileManager moveItemAtPath:source
                                 toPath:dest
                                  error:&error])
        {
            //TODO: Handle error
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error in the console:

NSFilePath=Test.pdf, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/Charley/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/96EB01D1-81B7-4ECE-B337-D2D663969EE3/Library/Caches, NSUnderlyingError=0xb566d50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"

Comment: FYI, the caches directory may be purged in low-storage space conditions. If you want to store these PDFs without this risk, you *can* still store them in the documents directory, but have to mark them to not be backed up (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/). However I would argue that user-downloaded PDFs *should* be backed up, and so that your original storage location is appropriate.

Comment: I agree, it should be backed up, but should I bother to refute my app's rejection?

Comment: If you believe it should and that it would provide a better user experience, then as long as the update isn't urgent, I would dispute it. Are these PDFs downloadable from anywhere, or is it all coming from the same source? The reason why I ask is because if those PDFs will always be accessible and easily re-downloadable, then I would say that they should *not* be backed up.

Comment: The PDFs are coming from one source, my server, and can be re-downloaded again easily, but I'm afraid this is going to piss off users because they have to re-download them over and over. Every time the user has to re-download something, they could be on 3G, and this will waist their monthly bandwidth.

Comment: True, but it will have to be uploaded to iCloud, which also uses data. I would suggest keeping a record of which PDFs have been downloaded and making sure *that* gets backed up. Then you can ask the user on restore whether they would like to re-download their PDFs. Just my opinion though.

Comment: You are right, but iCloud uses WiFi, and will not count against the user's 3G bandwidth. That is what my concern has been since day 1, and now Apple has screwed it up with the data storage guidelines.

Comment: Then why can't they download them over WiFi?

Comment: They can, but most people are on the go during their day, well at least in the conditions where this app is used in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use NSFileManager:

Get your documents path, and your caches path. Iterate over all the file, and move them using NSFileManager

```
- (void) moveAllDocs {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *sourceDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *destinationDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourceDirectory error:&error];

    for(NSString *sourceFileName in contents) {
        NSString *sourceFile = [sourceDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:sourceFileName];
        NSString *destFile = [destinationDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:sourceFileName];
        if(![fileManager moveItemAtPath:sourceFile toPath:destFile error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I added code to my original post, but I'm getting an error in the Console, as shown above, and the files aren't being moved. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: sounds like there's a copy already present in your caches folder. you need to remove the file from the destination or set an overwrite option

Comment: I deleted everything from the Caches directory before running the simulator again, so that can't be it?

Comment: Is there something I'm missing? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you had a few errors. 1. when you iterate over the directory, it just gives you a file name, not a full path. 2. When you move from source to destination, destination can't just be the directory name, it needs to include the file name appended onto the destination directory. See my edited answer for a working solution.

Comment: The 'file already exists' error was because you were trying to write a file name ONTO the already existing caches directory, not INSIDE the directory. It's a bit awkward, I know - and not very clear.